# Print full FileName from partial Name

Tags: c++

I have this question about C++,

I'm very new and wanted to print an output for my File name + the Version

This is the File

```
 TestFile[1.1.0].exe
```

I want Visual Studio to recognize only the

```
TestFile
```

And add the version number automatically, so if the Version changes, my application sets the new Version number.

I give Visual Studio:

```
TestFile
```

And in return it should print:

```
Testfile[1.1.0]
```

I didn't try anything because I don't even know where to start.
I think that it could look like this:

```cpp
cout << "TestFile" + VersionNumber" << endl;
```

What does "recognize" mean?

- With "recognize" I mean that I expect Visual Studio to detect any changes to the Numbers *inside* of the Brackets [ ].

What does "the Version changes" mean?

- With "the Version changes" I mean that whenever I edit the Numbers inside the Brackets [ ].

What does " automatically sets the new Version number" mean?

- With "automatically sets the new Version number" I mean that it automatically detects the changed Numbers in the Brackets [ ] and changes it's output accordingly.

Where do you define the version number? Is it in a text file somewhere?

- The Numbers are defined *inside* of the FileName -> TestFile **[1.1.0]** .exe

Alternatively, you define the version as a variable

- Good thought, altough I don't quite know how to do that.

Comment: Well it doesn't sound "too complicated" - it sounds too *vague*. See [ask].

Comment: What does "recognize" mean? What does "the Version changes" mean? What does " automatically sets the new Version number" mean? Please be specific, and explain your question while keeping in mind that whoever you're asking your question doesn't know what "recognize", "version changes", and "automatically setting" something means. Please pretend that a complete stranger walked off the street who doesn't know anything about your computer, and describe your question to this stranger.

Comment: Where do you define the version number? Is it in a text file somewhere? The usual approach is a post-build step that renames the resulting executable. You can set your project dependencies such that changes to the version file will require the project to be relinked. Alternatively, you define the version as a variable in the environment or property sheets, and properly form the output filename from that variable.

Comment: So you want to write a program that given a file prefix as input, looks for a file of that name in a folder with an attached version number and then outputs that full file name to the console? The problem with your question is that it is not clear how this file relates to your program or Visual Studio (which is the IDE, not your program). (I.e. what does "_I give Visual Studio:_" mean? Do you mean "_I give my program as input_" instead?)

Comment: @user17732522 *"I give my program as input"* Yes that is what I mean.  Yes that is what I would want my *program* to do :)

Comment: @Fear If you replaced "_Visual Studio_" with "_my program_" everywhere in the question it would already be much clearer.

Comment: However, it then has a good chance of being closed as too broad. For working with the file system we have [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) which you can use to iterate over the files in a directory, then you can use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string)'s functions to check if it the filename has the correct format and print the result if it does. You should make an attempt at that yourself and only ask if you have a specific problem while doing so.

Comment: Hope this [blog](https://helloacm.com/c-function-to-get-file-version-using-win32-api-ansi-and-unicode-version) is useful to you, another [solution](https://gist.github.com/superlucky8848/421afc4d3436ed09a21997126759e251) example

Answer (score 0):

What version of C++ do you use?
If you use C++ 20, you can use [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format)

Let us assume you have the following structure for your code:

```cpp
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    int major = 1; 
    int minor = 2; 
    int patch = 3;  

}
```

and you want the final string `TestFile[<major>,<minor>,<patch>].exe` as I understand it, then
you will have to write `std::cout << std::format("TestFile[{}.{}.{}].exe\n", major, minor, patch)`

Such that you can have the structure:

```cpp
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    int major = 1; 
    int minor = 2; 
    int patch = 3;  

    std::cout << std::format("TestFile[{}.{}.{}].exe\n", major, minor, patch);
}
```

If you are not in C++20 by C++{11,14,17} you can just do it like this instead (using [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)) if you want to stay only in the STL:

```cpp
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
    int major = 1; 
    int minor = 2; 
    int patch = 3;  

    std::cout << "TestFile" << std::to_string(major) << "." << std::to_string(minor) << "." << std::to_string(patch) << ".exe\n"; 
}
```

Finally if you are in C++{11,14,17} and want to use `std::format` like style of programming you can pull in the library [fmtlib](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) which is what `std::format` is based on.